# Best Approach to Storing Mean Uptime Data

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

We have 500+ remote locations. Each location has a linux router which checks in to our management system (homemade using RoR3) every 15 minutes.

We need to log and calculate mean uptime of each boxes Internet connectivity.

Each router posts a request every 15 minutes to a script on the server. (Currently this just records the last checkin time and the uptime.)

If we want to plot the historical uptime of each box, what is the most efficient way to do this without clogging our db up.

500 boxes checking in every 15 minutes would (according to my calculations) result in 17,520,000 inserts. Quite a hefty amount of data that I don't think we need.

Could anyone help solve this riddle for us?

Answer (score 1):

Why not take a look at [RRDTool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/) ([Wiki-entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RRDtool)). It's just the tool for this kind of situation.

It works as a sort of a round-robin self-averaging database, and it's used in many logging applications just for similar purposes to your situation.

As an example take a look at [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) which is a data-logging / network monitoring and graphing front-end app built around RRDTool (implemented in PHP).

Comment: Hi. We've thought about rrdtool or cacti but it wasn't really suitable as we need the data as part of our MySQL db. We've got a number of queries that need to be run on the uptime table.